Add cells to current jupyter notebook
I want to execute code in a jupyter notebook that appends a cell to the notebook that is executing the code and writes code in it.
e.g. in 'test.ipynb' execute code like this
name='test.ipynb'
code_str='{some_code}'
nb = nbf.read(f'{name}', as_version=4)
cells=[nbf.v4.new_code_cell(code_str)]
nb['cells'].extend(cells)
nbf.write(nb, f'{name}')

Ideally, a new cell should be created in 'test.ipynb' containing the new code. However, seemingly due to the notebook changing state while executing the code, it doesn't work.
VS Code issues an error (not in the notebook itself, at the VS Code application level) of
"Failed to save 'test.ipynb': The content of the file is newer. Do you want to overwrite the file with your changes?"
Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour?
Thanks

You can run that code in a different notebook or in Python or IPython. Alternatively, you can make  temp copy and then when you close the notebook replace the old one. You cannot run code inside a notebook that edits it;s own notebook with nbformat's write(). You can though use ipylab, I believe, see...

'I created a line magic for debugging to creates cells dynamically' and
'
How to programmatically add serveral new cells in a notebook in JupyterLab and here.
